# What I need to know if I want credit card payments in an ecommerce website

Tags: ecommerce, asp.net, payments, creditcard

I live in Costa Rica (in Central America). I want to build an eCommerce website with credit card payments, I know Asp.NET and SQL Server 2008.

I know Paypal and the express checkout solution, but many people (and clients) here don't like it or don't use it. Paypal and Authorize.Net don't support countries in Latin America. Please tell me about one company who can or what can I do to setup my shopping cart. I'm studying right now security and how to implement SSL certificates and encrypt sensible data and PCI compliance in some way. I need this for my own framework in ASP.NET and provide eCommerce solutions here in my country.

Comment: I think these "what payment processors will work in my country?" questions come up all too frequently. Maybe we should just create a community wiki question that lists them by country/continent so people can stop asking them. As for what else one needs to know before implementing CC processing on a website, that has probably also been covered in another question.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté I agree, especially with all the merchant account re-sellers who aren't really merchant providers that come and go often. Then you have the gateway re-sellers. A community wiki would be best so that if any site does go down we can comment on it to keep it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Authorize.Net or Paypal, you might look into FirstData (http://www.firstdata.com). I have used their PHP API before but they also offer an ASP and ASN.NET API for talking to their systems. They also service more than just North America, so it should also meet your international requirement.

Comment: Authorize.Net is not a payment provider. They are only a payment gateway.

Comment: So they aren't. My mistake.

Comment: Isn't FirstData formerly LinkPoint which was a gateway that was provided by Card Service International?